# How to create specific GUI Components for an Eclipse Plugin Preference Page?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, preference

My own created Preference Page doesn't look well formatted, due to the fact I don't know how to do so in java code (I don't want to use any editor for that case). I googled for some Tutorials, but they didn't help that much.

A documenatation or a tutorial where all possible GUI Components for Preference Pages were described and examples how to use them would be very helpflul.

Does somebody knows such pages ?

It would be very helpful to know how to make such a "box/panel" which contains other elements like a checkbox/radiobutton etc. In case to get the page more structured.
Example: Preferences -> General -> Open mode "box" with the RadioButtons "double click", "single click".

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is nothing special about the controls on preference pages, they are just normal SWT & JFace controls.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the best way to learn is by example. Find a preference page or another Eclipse screen that looks the way you want and study its source code. Eclipse has a very neat tool to make this easier. Simply hit ALT+SHIFT+F1 while on the screen you want to study further and you will get info about the class and the plugin that implement the screen. There are a variety of ways of getting the relevant source code at that point. Simply searching on Google with the full class name is often enough.